# Passing value by reference to Qore script function from C++ code

Tags: qore

I need pass *returnValue* to a method as argument passed by reference and adjust original var value when function id done. So using **ReferenceArgumentHelper** class.

What's wrong in code bellow when *returnValue* is unintentionally deleted (when it is a node, i.e. string) and valgrind detects it. *callMethod("onFunctionExit"* calls an Qore script method and I can see there correct *returnValue* value. I suspect it's deleted when exiting *onFunctionExit* when *ReferenceArgumentHelper* is destroyed. *rah.getArg()* references reference variable, so it should not be deleted in *callMethod*.

```
   DLLLOCAL ThreadDebugEnum callMethod(const char* name, const ThreadDebugEnum defaultResult, QoreProgram *pgm, int paramCount, AbstractQoreNode** params, ExceptionSink* xsink) {
      int rv;
      QoreListNode* l = new QoreListNode();
      qore_program_to_object_map_t::iterator i = qore_program_to_object_map.find(pgm);
      if (i == qore_program_to_object_map.end()) {
         return defaultResult;
      }
      i->second->ref();
      l->push(i->second);
      for (int i=0; i<paramCount; i++) {
         if (params[i])
               params[i]->ref();
         l->push(params[i]);
      }
      rv = qo->intEvalMethod(name, l, xsink);
      l->deref(xsink);
      return (ThreadDebugEnum) rv;
   }

   DLLLOCAL virtual ThreadDebugEnum onFunctionExit(QoreProgram *pgm, const StatementBlock *blockStatement, QoreValue& returnValue, ExceptionSink* xsink) {
      AbstractQoreNode* params[2];
      params[0] = getLocation(blockStatement);
      ReferenceArgumentHelper rah(returnValue.takeNode(), xsink); // grab node from returnValue and pass to helper
      params[1] = rah.getArg(); // caller owns ref
      ThreadDebugEnum rv = callMethod("onFunctionExit", DBG_SB_RUN, pgm, 2, params, xsink);
      AbstractQoreNode* rc = rah.getOutputValue();  // caller owns ref
      returnValue.assign(rc);  // takes reference
//      returnValue.ref();
      }
      return rv;
   }
```

When looking deeply I did not get why compiler is happy with code in */lib/ReferenceArgumentHelper.cpp*:

```
struct lvih_intern {
   LocalVar lv;
   ExceptionSink* xsink;
   ReferenceNode* ref;

   DLLLOCAL lvih_intern(AbstractQoreNode* val, ExceptionSink* xs) : lv("ref_arg_helper", 0), xsink(xs) {
      printd(5, "ReferenceArgumentHelper::ReferenceArgumentHelper() instantiating %p (val: %p type: '%s') \n", &lv, val, val ? val->getTypeName() : "n/a");
      lv.instantiate(val);   <--------------
      VarRefNode* vr = new VarRefNode(strdup("ref_arg_helper"), VT_LOCAL);
      vr->ref.id = &lv;
      ref = new ReferenceNode(vr, 0, vr, 0);
   }

class LocalVar {
....
   DLLLOCAL void instantiate(QoreValue nval) const {
```

What is behind conversion *AbstractQoreNode** to *QoreValue* in method call? I did not find an overloaded operator or so. I'm looking what exactly happens with references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** EDIT **

To make a long story short, `ReferenceArgumentHelper` was buggy; it hadn't been used in years and was not up to date.  The class has been fixed which should fix your issue I hope.

Thank you for pointing this out, and let me know if you have any further problems with this or the fix to the affected code.

Comment: I'm taking about *lv.instantiate(val);* where *val* is *AbstractCoreNode\** but method argument is *QoreValue* type.